# Ruby: self.call inside a class

Tags: ruby

Is there any difference between these two?

```
class Asdf
   def self.call
      puts "111"
   end
end
```

and

```
class Asdf
  def self.call
    new.call
  end

  def call
    puts "222"
  end
end
```

both can be called with `Asdf.call` . Is one a syntactic sugar of the other? Any performance difference between the two?

Comment: Well, obviously they are different. The former generates output right away whereas the latter first creates an instance and then calls an instance method in order to generate the output. Besides, the output is different. What do you mean, specifically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends entirely on what sort of data you're going to need for context when responding to that method call.

If there's no state involved, the class method approach works better since it doesn't require creating a temporary, and ultimately useless object.

Comment: It's not even clear why a class is necessary in this case. The simplest equivalent code would just be `def asdf_call; puts "hello"; end`.

Comment: A `module` could be useful from a namespace perspective.

Comment: Yeah, and Ruby has modules, so that would be more appropriate if we're just trying to namespace things. The problem with the question is that we're being asked to optimize "hello world", with no use case for it.